# Validate date format oracle

Tags: oracle, validation, date, testing, plsql

I would like to validate date column of a table with format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS'. The query i used so far is

```
select count(*) from table-name where not regexp-like(datefield,'/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/'
```

I would like to validate using a different method for the above requirement, like using sysdate format. Could someone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You would implicitly be validating the fields if you had just saved them as Datetime in the first place.

Comment: @cdaiga The data type shows just "DATE". Should it be DATE TIME?

Comment: if the datefield has a type `Date` then it is good. As a DATE type is able to store the data and the time in seconds.

Comment: What is the data type of column `datefield`? `DATE` or `VARCHAR2`? In case of `DATE`: Such validation is senseless. In case of `VARCHAR2`: What about invalid dates. e.g. `2018-99-99 12:65:76`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Its column with `DATE` data type

Comment: A `DATE` column does not have a format. Dates are stored in an internal representation. What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for your response. I just want to check if all the rows of the table are stored in the date time format as shown above. or should report if there are any rows if the date field is not in the particular format. Do i convert to string for this?

Comment: They aren't stored in *any* format. And `sysdate` also doesn't have a format; that is converted to a string for display, using your session NLS settings if you don't specify something specific. You can convert your stored values to strings too, with whatever string format you want, with `to_char()` for display, but they must be valid dates to have been stored in the first place. What you're trying to do doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @lifeofpy  Date datatypes have no format.  They are "date"  you control how the display occurs by NLS settings or by specifically casting the date using the [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)  So the reason why you're struggling is becuase a date is a date is a date. Format isn't "stored" in the database, it's a function of rendering to the screen which you can control via NLS or to_char or other methods...

Comment: To repeat what xQbert said, in slightly different words. You seem to believe that in addition to a date-time (such as March 22, 2013, 8:30 AM), a `date` column also stores a format model, such as `mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` for one row, another format model for another row, etc. **There is no such thing**. The data in the table is just the date-time in an internal Oracle format; no format model or "mask" for representing the date as a string, in one format or another, is stored **anywhere**. The format is only added (either by you or by Oracle at execution time) when you **display** date-times.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `datefield` is typed as `Date` there is no need to validate the field at the level of the database. You can do the validation/parsing in the application layer. To set a value to this field just use the [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) function.

```
datefield=TO_DATE('2018-02-26 17:55:55','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of the column "datefield"? 
If the column has a data type "**date**" then column itself has no format. 
Oracle doesn't store any format. 
It is your application (web, Oracle Forms, etc.) who applies the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS".